# What is the behavior of %(limit)[^\n] in scanf ? It is safety from overflow?

Tags: c, buffer, scanf, buffer-overflow

The format `%(limit)[^\n]` for `scanf` function is unsafe ? (where (limit) is the length -1 of the string)

If it is unsafe, why ?

And there is a safe way to implement a function that catch strings just using scanf() ?

On Linux Programmer's Manual, (typing man scanf on terminal), the `s` format said:

> Matches  a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null  byte  ('\0'),which  is  added  automatically.   The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

The input string stops at maximum field width always ? Or is just on GCC ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%(limit)[^\n]` for scanf" is usually safe.

In the below example, at *most* 99 `char` will be read and saved into `buf`.  If any `char` are saved, a `'\0'` will be appended and `cnt` will be 1.

```
char buf[100];
int cnt = scanf("%99[^\n]", buf);
```

*This* functionality is certainly *safe*, but what about others?

---

Problems occur when the input is a lone `"\n"`.

In this case, nothing is saved in `buf` and 0 is returned.  Had the next line of code been the following, the output is [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as `buf` is not initialized to anything.

```
puts(buf);
```

A better following line would be

```
if (cnt == 1) puts(buf);
else printf("Return count = %d\n", cnt);
```

Problems because the `'\n'` was not consumed.

The `'\n'` is still waiting to be read and another call to `scanf("%99[^\n]", buf);` will not read the `'\n'`.

---

Q: is a safe way to implement a function that catch strings just using scanf()
A: Pedantically: Not easily.

`scanf()`, `fgets()`, etc. are best used for reading *text*, not strings.  In C a string is an array of `char` terminated with a `'\0'`.  Input via `scanf()`, `fgets()`, etc. typically have issues reading `'\0'` and typically that `char` is not in the input anyways.  Usually input is thought of as groups of `char` terminated by `'\n'` or other white-space.

If code is reading input terminated with `'\n'`, using `fgets()` works well and is portable.  `fgets()` too has it weakness that are handled in various ways .  `getline()` is a nice alternative.

A close approximate would be `scanf(" %99[^\n]", buf)` (note the added `" "`), but alone that does not solve handing excessive long lines, reading multiple empty lines, embedded `'\0'` detection, loss of ability to report length read (`strlen()` does not work due to embedded `'\0'`) and its leaving the trailing `'\n`' in `stdin`.

Short of using `scanf("%c", &ch)` with lots of surrounding code (which is silly, just use `fgetc()`) , I see no way to use a single `scanf()` absolutely safely when reading a line of user input.

---

Q: The input string stops at maximum field width always ?
A: With `scanf("%99[^\n]"`, input stops 1) when a `'\n'` is encountered - the `'\n'` is not saved and remains in the file input buffer  2) 99 `char` have been read 3) EOF occurs or 4) IO error occurs (rare).

Comment: What does the added space in `scanf(" %99[^\n], buf)` mean ? And, the last question, when the format is `℅s` the input string stops at maximum field width always ?

Comment: @X0R40 The space in `scanf(" %99[^\n], buf)` scans, but not saves any leading white-space before saving non-`'\n'` to `buf`.  Without this, should input begin with `'\n'`, not only is nothing saved, but the `'\n'` remains in `stdin`, blocking any further input.

Comment: @X0R40 when the format is `℅s`, the input string does not stop at the fields width as none was given.  With  `℅99s`, the input always stops once 99 non-white-space `char` are read.  Of course input will stop earlier once some data is saved and white-space occurs or EOF or IO error.

Comment: Just one more question. To make scanf safe, should I use after `scanf(" %99[^\n]", buf)` something to clean the buffer like `while((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')` ?

Comment: @X0R40 Before `scanf(" %99[^\n]", buf)`, add `buf[0] = 0;`.  Afterwards `while((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')`.  Best to place in a helper function, maybe called `X0R40_Getline100(char *);`.

Comment: But it is not still the safest way of getting user input because, even we clear the buffer, may still be a risk for having unwanted things in the buffer that can be used for injection of malicious code in stack. Or I am wrong ?

Comment: @X0R40 1) The 99 in `"%99[^\n]"` limits the data saved -safe from overflow.  Should the bad guys attempt to inject 100s of `char`, code only saves 99.  The while loop consumes and tosses the rest.  Should the user only enter `"\n"`, code is covered too with the `buf[0] = 0;`.  All this makes the code "safer".  Should you want "safest" code, would not use `scanf()` at all, but `fgetc()`.  Pedantically, safety is context dependent, and this post does not provide enough design parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The [^\n] is to make scanf read input until it meets a new line character...while the limit is the maximum number of characters scanf should read...

Comment: Or you can use gets()